# Android Navigation drawer transparent bug

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, arcore, android-navigationview

I have an issue using the navigation drawer in combination with the AR-Fragment from googles arcore sdk, here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

When I change the current fragment it works as intended.
Code inside the onCreate-Method of the Activity:

```
drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
drawerLayout.bringToFront();
navigationView.bringToFront();

arFragment = new ArSceneFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.fragment_container, arFragment).commit();
```

Hope you can help me:)
Thank you and best regards!

**EDIT:**
When I test using the emulator it works perfectly.

Comment: I suspect that it's something with a title bar. check your Manifest file and see if you set the theme as NoActionBar. if not, try to change it.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I already set the theme as NoActionBar... The other strange thing is, that it works perfectly inside the emulator :(

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
if (!drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
   drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
} else {
   drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
}
```

when you open and close the drawer.

and i'm still suspecting the title bar.
Cuz i had a almost same problem before and it was about title bar.
Sometimes eventho you set the theme as NoActionBar in your layout xml,
the Manifest file doesn't automatically updates it. so you need to check it twice.

Comment: Well that didn't work either :( I checked Manifest and there is NoActionBar configured.. When I'm other menu points without the AR fragment it works perfectly... so I guess it has to do with the AR Fragment?

Comment: @MBPictures in that case, I have no idea. sorry. but one more thing i checked your code and have question. are you using actionbar's nav button to open and close the drawer? cuz in my case since i didn't  use actionbar. i made a img button with hamburger menu image, and gave it function to open and close the drawer.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways! Yes I use the ActionBarDrawerToggle to open/close the nav view. It adds the hamburger and automatically animates it on open/close. Is this a problem? Every tutorial I watched implements the drawer layout this way.